# Database datasource binding for multiple app and instance

Tags: cloudbees

We use a single mysql database for 2 applications. One of this application has 2 instances.

So we would like to know how cloudbees manage the connexion pool between all these apps. I saw in other threads that mysql default conf on cloudbees accept 20 connections. For the moment, we use "old" hibernate configuration with explicite c3p0 but we thought that they could try to open too much connexions on the db.

If we change the conf to use jndi cloudbees datasource (as describ here https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide), should our apps share the same connection pool ? Or at least all instances of each app ?

Hope it's understandable. Let me know if not.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of the app has its own connection pool - so you need to consider that in sizing the pool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, if I want to use auto scaling from 2 to 10 instances, I have to set the max connection to 2 ? Or there is an other way to handle this problem ?

Comment: depending on the database size - more connections can be available for this - maybe best is to open a support ticket so we can ensure you get what you need.

Comment: For the moment it's only a theoretical question, we don't use auto-scaling so far. But it sounds like a common problem so I'm surprised that this does not..

Comment: yes this is mainly the difference between free and paid that you are seeing.